# Is it possible to get the history of changes on a build definition in TFS2010?

Tags: tfsbuild

It seems odd that the main build definitions would not have a history, but I can't find any mechanisms. Please tell me there is someway to track changes to the build definitions over time.

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never. I just had the same issue and I found the solution, by chance. For TFS version 15, this is how to do it:

1. Go to your build definition;
2. Click on the Edit button;
3. Now you have a History tab (the last one for me).  Click on it and you will see the change history.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Was able to find the version was looking for and revert back

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there is no way to track the changes to the build definition automatically. You can however do it manually by exporting the definition to a file each time you change it and then checking in that file into source control.

You'll need to install the Team Foundation Server Power Tools appropriate for your TFS version, then you can use

tfpt builddefinition

to export definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Look in source control under:

```
$/ProjectName/TeamBuildTypes
```

There should be a full history of changes to the <>.proj file stored there.

Comment: those .proj files are from team build 2008, the same structure and files do not exist in TFS 2010. That is the whole problem, there is no file saved anywhere. It must just keep the build steps in the database.

Comment: Thanks for that update.  I figured because TFS 2010 made the TeamBuildTypes directory, that it would populate it with something.

Comment: Alex-- I still haven't found anything on the inherent ability to track build changes over time, but one thing you could do is export the build and store that in source control.  Kludgy, but might work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .proj files in TFS 2010 builds (for backwards compatibility).  So, if you really needed to track changes, just add the .proj file to the appropriate TeamBuildTypes folder.  When you create the build definition, on the Process form,  you need to change Build process file to 'Upgrade Template' and then specify the Configuration Folder Path under Build process parameters.